# How to find the closed form of $\int_{0}^{\infty}{(e^{-x}+x-1)^2\over x(e^{x\over n}-1)}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

We partially guessed the closed form of $(1)$ to be

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{(e^{-x}+x-1)^2\over x(e^{x\over n}-1)}\mathrm dx=f(n)+{\pi^2\over 6}n^2+\ln{{2n\choose n}}\tag1$$

where $n\ge1$

$f(1)=-2$

$f(2)=-6$

$f(3)=-11$

$f(4)=-{50\over 3}$

$f(5)=-{137\over 6}$

$f(n)=?$

**How can we find the complete closed form for $(1)?$**

Comment: for what stands $n$ here?

Comment: an integer be most suited

Comment: Expand $\int_0^\infty\frac{(e^{-x}+x-1)^2}{x(e^{x\over n}-1)} dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}(e^{-2x}+x^2+1 +2x e^{-x}-2x-2e^{-x}) e^{-kx/n}dx$ and use that $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-mx}dx = m^{-s} \Gamma(s)$ and express the result in term of the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint by user `reuns`:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{(\exp (-x)+x-1)^2}{x \left(\exp \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-1\right)} \, dx & =\int_0^{\infty } \frac{(\exp
   (-x)+x-1)^2 \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \exp \left(-\frac{k x}{n}\right)}{x} \, dx \\
&=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty }
   \frac{(\exp (-x)+x-1)^2 \exp \left(-\frac{k x}{n}\right)}{x} \, dx \\
&=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{n^2 (-k+n)}{k^2 (k+n)}+2
   \ln (k+n)-\ln (k (k+2 n))\right) \\
&=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{n^2 (-k+n)}{k^2 (k+n)}+\ln \left(\frac{(k+n)^2}{k (k+2
   n)}\right)\right) \\
&=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^2 (-k+n)}{k^2 (k+n)}+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \ln \left(\frac{(k+n)^2}{k (k+2
   n)}\right) \\
&=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{n^2 (-k+n)}{k^2 (k+n)}+\ln \left(\prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(k+n)^2}{k (k+2
   n)}\right) \\
&=-2 \gamma  n+\frac{n^2 \pi ^2}{6}-2 n \, \psi (1+n)+\ln \left(\frac{4^n \,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)}{\sqrt{\pi
   } \,\Gamma (1+n)}\right) \\
&=-2 n H_n+\frac{n^2 \pi ^2}{6}+\ln \left(\binom{2 n}{n}\right)
\end{align}$$

where

- $\gamma$ is  [Euler’s constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) $=0.577216...$
- $\psi (1+n) $ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)
- $H_n$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)

Comment: Well done. (+1)  :-)